# How to flatten (compress) multi-dimensional array into one-dimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, type-conversion, associative-array

I got this array. I want all the other 3 array come into this  [0] => Array. Don't want unique value just want to merge all array flat in to  [0] => Array.

```
Array
 (
  [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Campaign] => xxx
                [Phone] => 111
                [State] => cd
            )

         )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Campaign] => zxxxzx
                [Phone] => 111111
                [State] => zxxx
            )

         )

  [2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Campaign] => aaaa
                [Phone] => 111
                [State] => Csd
            )

        )

  [3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Campaign] => sasa
                [Phone] => 111
                [State] => asas
            )

          )
)
```

Comment: What exactly should the resulting array look like?

Answer (score 1):

This is another example of how important the naming is. What you are working with is basically:

```
$recordsGroups = array(
    // first group:
    array(
        // record 1:
        array(
            'key1' => 'val1',
            'key2' => 'val2',
        ),
        // record 2:
        array(
            'key1' => 'aaa',
            'key2' => 'bbb',
        ),
    ),
    // 2nd group:
    array(
        // record 3:
        array(
            'key1' => 'ccc',
            'key2' => 'ddd',
        ),
    ),
);
```

And what you are probably trying to do is:

```
$records = array();
foreach ($recordsGroups as $group)
    foreach ($group as $record)
        $records[] = $record;
```

Which will give you:

```
$records = array(
    // record 1:
    array(
        'key1' => 'val1',
        'key2' => 'val2',
    ),
    // record 2:
    array(
        'key1' => 'aaa',
        'key2' => 'bbb',
    ),
    // record 3:
    array(
        'key1' => 'ccc',
        'key2' => 'ddd',
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do nicely:

```
$array = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```

Or [Argument unpacking via ...](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat) (splat operator):

```
$array = array_merge(...$array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because arrays can't have duplicate keys, the best that this multi-dim array can be condensed is down to an indexed array of associative arrays.  `array_column()` will make quick work of this task.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a75ff130ea74b7b8581423710430ac53e690b978))

```
$array=[
    [
        ['Campaign'=>'xxx','Phone'=>'111','State'=>'cd']
    ],
    [
        ['Campaign'=>'zxxxzx','Phone'=>'111111','State'=>'zxxx']
    ],
    [
        ['Campaign'=>'aaaa','Phone'=>'111','State'=>'Csd']
    ],
    [
        ['Campaign'=>'sasa','Phone'=>'111','State'=>'asas']
    ]
];

var_export(array_column($array,0));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'Campaign' => 'xxx',
    'Phone' => '111',
    'State' => 'cd',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'Campaign' => 'zxxxzx',
    'Phone' => '111111',
    'State' => 'zxxx',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'Campaign' => 'aaaa',
    'Phone' => '111',
    'State' => 'Csd',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'Campaign' => 'sasa',
    'Phone' => '111',
    'State' => 'asas',
  ),
)
```